# Issue with iOS7 and UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController that is added as subview on UIView. The UIView sits on the top of UIViewController's view, at start it puts the UIPageViewController lower than it should sit, but right after I click on the next button to push the next UIPageViewController's view, it send it back to the correct position.

What is he doing that? I tried everything but still can figure out the problem.

This is how it looks:

[image]

What seems to be the problem? Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT: This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

    DataChildViewController *initialViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:initialViewController];
    [self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    self.pageController.dataSource = self;
    self.pageController.delegate = self;
    self.pageController.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    self.pageController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.pageControllerParent addSubview:self.pageController.view];
    [self addChildViewController:self.pageController];

    self.currentPageControllerIndex = 1;
}

- (IBAction)buttonNextDidClicked
{
    self.buttonNext.enabled = NO;
    __weak typeof(self) __self = self;
    [self.pageController setViewControllers:@[[self viewControllerAtIndex:self.currentPageControllerIndex]]
                                  direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                   animated:YES
                                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                     __self.currentPageControllerIndex++;
                                     __self.buttonNext.enabled = YES;
                                 }];
}

#pragma mark - UIPageViewControllerDelegate & DataSource

- (DataChildViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    DataChildViewController *childViewController = [[DataChildViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DataChildViewController" bundle:nil];
    childViewController.index = index;

    return childViewController;
}
```

Comment: Could you give me code that you create PageController1, and you assign it to UIPageViewController. I think it is due to setFrame function. Double check it.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've figured out the problem.

On viewDidLoad I had this line:

```
self.pageController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

When it actually should be:

```
self.pageController.view.frame = self.pageControllerParent.bounds;
```